# Leaderelections failing, lease unable to be renewed automatically

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver, leader-election, kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager

I have a production cluster is currently running on K8s version `1.19.9`, where the kube-scheduler and kube-controller-manager failed to have leader elections. The leader is able to acquire the first lease, however it then cannot renew/reacquire the lease, this has caused other pods to constantly in the loop of electing leaders as none of them could stay on long enough to process anything/stay on long enough to do anything meaningful and they time out, where another pod will take the new lease; this happens from node to node. Here are the logs:

```
E1201 22:15:54.818902       1 request.go:1001] Unexpected error when reading response body: context deadline exceeded
E1201 22:15:54.819079       1 leaderelection.go:361] Failed to update lock: resource name may not be empty
I1201 22:15:54.819137       1 leaderelection.go:278] failed to renew lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager: timed out waiting for the condition
F1201 22:15:54.819176       1 controllermanager.go:293] leaderelection lost
```

Detailed Docker logs:

```
Flag --port has been deprecated, see --secure-port instead.
I1201 22:14:10.374271       1 serving.go:331] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
I1201 22:14:10.735495       1 controllermanager.go:175] Version: v1.19.9+vmware.1
I1201 22:14:10.736289       1 dynamic_cafile_content.go:167] Starting request-header::/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
I1201 22:14:10.736302       1 dynamic_cafile_content.go:167] Starting client-ca-bundle::/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
I1201 22:14:10.736684       1 secure_serving.go:197] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:10257
I1201 22:14:10.736747       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/kube-controller-manager...
I1201 22:14:10.736868       1 tlsconfig.go:240] Starting DynamicServingCertificateController
E1201 22:14:20.737137       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://[IP address]:[Port]/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
E1201 22:14:32.803658       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://[IP address]:[Port]/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
E1201 22:14:44.842075       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get "https://[IP address]:[Port]/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
E1201 22:15:13.386932       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: context deadline exceeded
I1201 22:15:44.818571       1 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager
I1201 22:15:44.818755       1 event.go:291] "Event occurred" object="kube-system/kube-controller-manager" kind="Endpoints" apiVersion="v1" type="Normal" reason="LeaderElection" message="master001_1d360610-1111-xxxx-aaaa-9999 became leader"
I1201 22:15:44.818790       1 event.go:291] "Event occurred" object="kube-system/kube-controller-manager" kind="Lease" apiVersion="coordination.k8s.io/v1" type="Normal" reason="LeaderElection" message="master001_1d360610-1111-xxxx-aaaa-9999 became leader"
E1201 22:15:54.818902       1 request.go:1001] Unexpected error when reading response body: context deadline exceeded
E1201 22:15:54.819079       1 leaderelection.go:361] Failed to update lock: resource name may not be empty
I1201 22:15:54.819137       1 leaderelection.go:278] failed to renew lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager: timed out waiting for the condition
F1201 22:15:54.819176       1 controllermanager.go:293] leaderelection lost
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0xc00000e001, 0xc000fb20d0, 0x4c, 0xc6)
    /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:996 +0xb9
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x6a57fa0, 0xc000000003, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000472070, 0x68d5705, 0x14, 0x125, 0x0)
    /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:945 +0x191
```

My duct tape recovery method was to shutdown the other candidates and disable leader elections `--leader-elect=false`. We manually set a leader and let it stay on for a while, then reactivated leader elections after. This has seemed to work as intended again, the leases are renewing normally after.

Could it be possible that the api-server may be too overwhelmed to expend any resources(?), because the elections have failed due to timeout? Was wondering if anyone has ever encountered such an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@**janeosaka**,  you are right This problem occurs when you have a `1)resource crunch` or `2)network issue`.

It seems the leader election API call is getting timeout as Kube API Server had a resource crunch and it has increased the latency of API calls.

**1)Resource Crunch :** (**Increasing the CPU and Memory of the nodes**)

It seems that it is the expected behavior. When the leader election fails the controller is not able to renew the lease and per design the controller is restarted to ensure that a single controller is active at a time.

LeaseDuration and RenewDeadline (RenewDeadline is the duration that the acting master will retry), are [configurable in controller-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/pkg/manager/manager.go#L177-L186).

Another approach you may consider is to leverage [API Priority & Fairness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/flow-control/)  to increase the chances of success of the calls made to the API by your controller if it is not at  the origin of the API overload.

**2)Network Issue :**
If it is a network issue : (The leader election lost is a symptom that the host has network problems, not a cause).

```
Check the issue may resolve after restarting the SDN pod
```

`"sdn-controller"` and `"sdn"` are very different things. If restarting an *sdn* pod fixed things, then the *sdn-controller* the error you noticed was not the actual problem.

Comment: @Janeosaka, Please let me know above answer is helpful? and also let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was looking at the [documentation on leader election and lease durations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/)
Would it then be accurate to say that `--leader-elect-retry-period duration` will increase the time for other candidates to attempt taking over the lease from the currently elected leader?

Comment: Correct timeout value depends on the storage backend and how quickly it is able to processes ControllerPublish and ControllerUnpublish calls. The value should be set to accommodate majority of them. It is fine if some calls time out - such calls will be re-tried after exponential backoff (starting with --retry-interval-start), however, this backoff will introduce delay when the call times out several times for a single volume (up to --retry-interval-max).

Comment: See [CSI error and timeout handling](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-attacher/blob/master/README.md#csi-error-and-timeout-handling) for more info.

Comment: Yes, the initial answer is helpful, it points me towards the right direction, thank you so much. It seems like the CSI error and timeout handling isn't something that could help my cause, but I appreciate you sharing further resources. Thanks once again, take care!